# Vanquishing a dragon using one dimensional random walk with variable path lengths

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations, markov-chains, random-walk

My friend posed a question a couple of days back which states the following. There is a dragon which starts with 3 heads, and we can cut one head at a time. Everytime we cut one head, either nothing happens, two heads grow back or three heads grow back. We are asked to find the probability of cutting off all heads.

So I modelled this as a random walk on $\mathbb Z$ with an absorbing barrier at $x=0$. We either go back one step, go forward one step or go forwards two steps, each with equal probability. Let us take $P_k$ to be the probability of starting at $x=k$ and hitting $x=0$ eventually. We then need to find $P_3$. The recursion I am looking at is $$3P_k=P_{k-2}+P_{k-1}+P_{k+1}$$ with the obvious boundary condition $P_0=1$. The solution to this recurrence is $$P_k=A+B(1-\sqrt2)^k+C(1+\sqrt2)^k$$ with $A+B+C=1$. I want my probabilities to be bounded, so $C$ must be $0$.

But here I am stuck. I would need one more boundary condition to proceed, which I am not sure what it might be. I am trying to look at the fact that the mean motion is $2/3$ steps to the right and hence the probability of eventually getting absorbed must decrease (and hence $A=0$? But then the probabilites are negative at odd values of $k$).

I am at a loss how to proceed, or maybe I have done something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @Balajisb I am assuming $P_0=1$ becaise of the way we are defining $P_k$. It is defined as the probability of eventually hitting 0. Hence if we start from 0, we have already reached 0 and thus the probability is 1

Comment: Thanks HackR. I agree. I deleted my comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have the recurrence slightly wrong and it should be $P_k= \frac13 P_{k-1}+\frac13P_{k+1}+ \frac13 P_{k+2}$ for $k > 0$ i.e. $$3P_k=P_{k-1}+P_{k+1}+ P_{k+2}$$

You are missing the key observation that $P_0=1$, $P_2=P_1^2$, and in general $P_k=P^k_1$.  You want all of any descendents of each the $k$ heads to eventually die out.

So you want to solve $x^3+x^2-3x+1=0$ to find $P_1$, which has the roots $1$, $-\sqrt{2}-1$ and $\sqrt{2}-1$.  The first two of those are implausible (the probability is positive, but there is also a positive probability the number of heads will explode), so $P_1=\sqrt{2}-1\approx 0.414$.

Since the dragon starts with $3$ heads, you actually want $P_3=P_1^3 = \sqrt{50}-7\approx 0.071$.

Comment: I think the recurrence should be: $3P_k = P_{k-1} + P_k +P_{k+1}$ ?

Comment: Ah yes, I messed up the recurrence. That makes sense. I'll look at the new recurrence and see what I can get. Thank you.

Comment: @Balajisb yours would be "cut off one head and see zero or one or two grow back"

Comment: Yes. If you have a different definition, can you clarify in the answer ? Also it will then be clear why $P_k = P_1^k$

Comment: @Balajisb The question says "Everytime we cut one head, either nothing happens, two heads grow back or three heads grow back" which is different.

Comment: @Balajisb $P_k = P_1^k$ because you want all of any descendents of each the $k$ heads to eventually die out.  With independent events you can multiply probabilities

Comment: @Henry $P_k = P_1^k$ only if you want to reach $0$ in $k$ steps ? Seem not obvious although could be true.

Comment: @Balajisb No - $P_1$ is "eventually" which is why it is greater than $\frac13$ and $P_k$ is also "eventually" which is why it is greater than $\frac{1}{3^k}$

Comment: @Balajisb it is just the multiplication of probabilities of independent events

Comment: +1. Nice answer.

Comment: I agree, its just that the problem is not symmetric w.r.t $k$ for very $k$ to say that $P(moving \ from \ k \ to \ k-1 \ eventually) = P_1$ since for $k = 2$ you can go to state 1 and come back to state 2. But for $k = 5$, you can go to state 1,2,3,4 and come back to state $5$. You seem to be assuming some form of symmetry ?

Comment: @Balajisb, it seems that you miss the point. We don't care about what happens after we reach $k-1$ from $k$; what we really care about is *whether* we reach $k-1$ at all.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense. Thanks zhoraster and Henry.